# List compression not returning the empty list value

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The general form of a list comprehension is:

```
[<map expression> for <name> in <sequence expression> if <filter expression>]
```

Example code:

```
subsets = [[]]
n = 1
[s + [n] for s in subsets]
```

Expected output:

```
[[[], 1]]
```

Actual output:

```
[[1]]
```

Why does the `s` empty list get filtered before the output in the list comprehension? If I had an `if statement` after the sequence expression that would be a filter on the output. If you add to an empty list you get back the code below which makes sense. Clearly I am missing something fundamental to list comprehension.

```
subsets + [1]
>>> [[], 1]
```

Comment: `subsets + [1]` isn't what your listcomp is doing, it's more like `subsets[0] + [1]` - which is effectively `[] + [1]`, which is indeed `[1]`.

Comment: `[s for s in subsets] + [n]` (or just `subsets + [n]`, I'm not sure why you don't just use that) gives you the output you desire, but I suspect you must want something different. What do you expect the output to be if subsets already has data in it?

Comment: @jasonharper if 'subsets = []'  instead why would the list comprehension return '[]' then and not '[1]'?

Comment: @JolonB I am trying to understand the solution for https://cs61a.org/disc/disc06_sol.pdf problem 2.2

Comment: If `subsets = []`, then your listcomp executes zero times, and an empty list is the only possible result.

Answer (score 2):

```
subsets = [[]]
n = 1
[s + [[],n] for s in subsets]
```

> **In your code when you are doing a list compression in for loop you are getting a list. And you are performing a concatenate operation on the list. And that is why you are getting a list like [[1]]**

Comment: I get it thanks! I am concatenating each iterable in the list so that is what the [] + [1] = [1]

Answer (score -1):

```
subsets=[[[]]]
[s + [n] for s in subsets]
```

if subsets = [[]], it means there is an empty list in the big list. that means, s = [], [n] = [1], so s+[n] = [1], you get the above result [[1]].